# How do I draw dot on the screen?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I am beginner, currently doing embedded system, using stm32 and c language to display word. But I don't how to use data from http://dotmatrixtool.com/

Here is my attempt. I made data into 2D array, `const uint8_t data[8][16]`

```
if (__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_GET_IT(GPIO_PIN_13) != RESET)
{
    LCD_Clear (0, 0, 240, 320, BACKGROUND); //data
    uint8_t ucTemp, ucPage, ucColumn;

    //ucRelativePositon = cChar - ' ';

    LCD_OpenWindow ( 100, 100, 32, 32 );

    LCD_Write_Cmd ( CMD_SetPixel );

    for ( ucPage = 0; ucPage < 16; ucPage ++ )
    {
        for ( ucColumn = 0; ucColumn < 8; ucColumn ++)
        {
            ucTemp = data [ucPage][ucColumn];
            if ( ucTemp & 0x01 )
                LCD_Write_Data ( 0x001F );

            else
                LCD_Write_Data (  0xFFFF );

            ucTemp >>= 1;

        }

    }
```

Comment: `ucTemp >>= 1;` doesn't really do anything, since you just reload `ucTemp` on the next iteration of the loop anyway.

Comment: `const uint8_t data[8][16]` cannot be accessed as `for ( ucPage = 0; ucPage < 16; ucPage ++ )`, you've mixed up the dimensions either in the declaration or in the for loops.